# MySQL ST_CONTAINS on Overlap case

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I'm facing a problem using the ST_CONTAINS geospatial function on MySQL 5.6.31.

I've the following MULTIPOLYGON:

[image: MULTIPOLYGON]

I need to check if some point is inside a MULTIPOLYGON, in this case the red one on the image, so i do:

```
SET @g1 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('MULTIPOLYGON(((41.94142040508967 12.41757292797851,41.94442097040815 12.419032049682611,41.93529115206086 12.43456740429687,41.91939065648979 12.425126028564447,41.92475512204906 12.407702398803705,41.94142040508967 12.41757292797851),(41.92552143745503 12.409933996704096,41.90987400689221 12.402638388183588,41.90252797153794 12.421864462402338,41.907446714803015 12.433194113281244,41.92603230927889 12.419461203124994,41.92552143745503 12.409933996704096,41.92552143745503 12.409933996704096),(41.906248516384416 12.397567221513638,41.89551602293968 12.423402258745083,41.90101026279693 12.430268713823208,41.90771770545893 12.420398184648404,41.91033661082307 12.39653725325192,41.906248516384416 12.397567221513599,41.906248516384416 12.397567221513599,41.906248516384416 12.397567221513638,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.39756722151363,41.906248516384416 12.397567221513638)))');

SET @g2 = POINT(41.9059998,12.4159939);

SELECT ST_CONTAINS(@g1,@g2);
```

The result is 0.

If i change the point, specifying for example a point in the upper polygon, i got 1.

Why this behaviour? It seems that when two polygons overlaps the ST_CONTAINS see it as en empty part of them.

What can i do?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird (not standard compliant and probably invalid) multipolygon.

Multipolygon is described as something like:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((p1_shell), (p1_hole1), (p1_hole2)), ((p2_shell), (p2_hole1), (p2_hole2)))
```

I.e. polygons are separated by double round brackets, and polygon shell is separated from holes by single round brackets. In your case it is single brackets - so this WKT describes a **single** polygon with two **holes**! Note that it is not a valid one (you can call `ST_IsValid` to check) - the hole is not fully contained within the shell as required by standard But anyway MySql allows this, and since the red point is within hole, it is not contained by the shape, so MySql result is correct.

If the desired semantic of the shape is a multipolygon, not polygon with holes, replace `),(` with `)),((` to get that semantics. Note that this is still not valid WKT shape - individual polygons in a multipolygon are not allowed to intersect (again check with `ST_IsValid`). But it should give you correct result anyway (although, being non-standard, this is somewhat undefined behavior).

If you want to be standard-compliant, you should clean this WKT. What you do depends on semantics you need. Maybe ST_UNION these polygons and get a single one. Or to keep all three - the correct way to describe a shape consisting of possibly intersecting polygons is `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` with polygons as members.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately i'm not able to user ST_IsValid() because in MySQL 5.6 there's not the function.
I'm close to switch from 5.6 to 8.0 and i'm going to fix all these not standard records.